# How to write PHP code to evaluate client IP?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal 7.x website deployed and I need help with using the below function and returning a true/false based on IP (more info below). I am trying to use this in Drupal's Rules module.

Drupal comes with a built-in function..

```
<?php
  print ip_address();
?>
```

This returns the client's IP address in the form of an ipv4 address such as 172.16.14.100 (example). (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/ip_address/7)

I need to be able to grab ip_address(); and evaluate it in PHP, i want the evaluation to return a boolean value (return TRUE) if the ip_address() is in the range of 172.16.1.1 - 172.16.255.255 and false if it is not.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: See answer but for such a simple range, a dirty hack would be to test if the IP begins with "172.16" with a regexp if you don't want to bother using ip functions ;-)

Comment: Capsule, can you show an example how one would do this with regexp?

Comment: Come on, it's not a programming course... At least read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) to change the IPv4 address into a long integer and use that for comparison.

```
$example_ip = ip2long("192.168.1.1");
$high_ip = ip2long("172.16.255.255");
$low_ip = ip2long("172.16.1.1");
if ($example_ip <= $high_ip && $low_ip <= $example_ip) {
  return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: After some modification, this worked for what I needed. Thank you!